# How to do custom image cropping in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my application, I need to take images from gallery/camera, crop those images, then save the cropped images some where else. The below code does most of that, but cannot crop images to my liking. Using the below code, I can crop images using 4 coordinates, top, bottom, left and right side of image middle coordinates; but I need to crop using 8 coordinates. [This image](https://twitter.com/radhasweety7/status/336806203579580416/photo/1) shows what I mean.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
  private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
  private static final int PRESS_OK = 3;
  ImageView imgview;
  String m_path;
  Bitmap m_thePic;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_camera);
    Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_gallery);
    Button buttonOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Images/");
    folder.mkdirs();
    buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // call android default camera
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        // ******** code for crop image
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

        try {
          intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
          startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          // Do nothing for now
        }
      }
    });
    buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // call android default gallery
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // ******** code for crop image
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

        try {
          intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
          startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          // Do nothing for now
        }
      }
    });
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String m_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File m_imgDirectory = new File(m_path + "/Images/");
        File m_file = new File(m_path);
        String m_fileid = "nm_tech" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        m_file = new File(m_path, "/Images/" + m_fileid + ".jpg");
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(m_file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                   ImageGalleryDemoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image", m_fileid);
        startActivity(intent);
        // startActivityForResult(intent,PRESS_OK);
        // call android default camera
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ,1234).show();
      }
    });
  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap m_thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
    String m_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File m_imgDirectory = new File(m_path + "/Images/");
    if (!m_imgDirectory.exists()) {
      m_imgDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream m_fOut = null;
    File m_file = new File(m_path);
    m_file.delete();
    String m_fileid = "nm_tech" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
    m_file = new File(m_path, "/Images/" + m_fileid + ".jpg");
    try {
      if (!m_file.exists()) {
        m_file.createNewFile();
      }
      m_fOut = new FileOutputStream(m_file);
      Bitmap m_bitmap = m_thePic.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
      m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, m_fOut);
      m_fOut.flush();
      m_fOut.close();
      MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                      m_file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                          m_file.getName(),
                                          m_file.getName());
    } catch (Exception p_e) {
    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
      if (extras != null) {
        // Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
        imgview.setImageBitmap(m_thePic);
      }
    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
      // Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
        imgview.setImageBitmap(m_thePic);
      }
    }

    if (requestCode == PRESS_OK) {
      Bundle extras11 = data.getExtras();
      Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

      /*
       * Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
       * imgview.setImageBitmap(photo); Intent n=new
       * Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageGalleryDemoActivity.class);
       * n.putExtra("data",photo); startActivity(n);
       */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Image must be a rectangle when it is saved, so what do you want to be the empty area? Transparent, black? You can go through your points and find minimum Rect needed to hold your image, then paint your image part on your new image, then using paths or whatever you fill like it remove your empty rectangles on the side. Little bit of math but...

Comment: thnkyou,empty area not my prblm...any way i want to fill transparent noprblm...normal using my code 1 can able to crop using 4 points left,top,right and bottom sides,see my image once here 8 points is threre using those ponts i have to crop my image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way for you to create minimum needed rect from an array of coordinates

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Rect r = getRect(new int[]{10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30}, new int[]{20, 100, 10, 110, 20, 100});
    System.out.println(r.left + " " + r.top + " " + r.bottom + " " + r.right);
}

public Rect getRect(int[] x, int y[]){
    Rect r = new Rect();
        // Set the first coordinate, in order not to include 0, 0
    r.set(x[0], y[0], x[0], y[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
        r.union(x[i], y[i]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

EDIT: look you have 8 points, just call this getRect like this

```
Rect rectToDraw = getRect(new int{yourx1, yourx2, yourx3, yourx4, yourx5, yourx6, yourx7, yourx8,}, new int{youry1, youry2, youry3, youry4, youry5, youry6, youry7, youry8});
```

You can pass this function ass many points you want, not just 8

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: this is just to define a common Rect for all your coordinates, and here is where I pasted example array `Rect r = getRect(new int[]{10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30}, new int[]{20, 100, 10, 110, 20, 100});`. Then get bottom, left, top and right from rect. As I can see you can do drawing by yourself.

Comment: i have to crop image based 8 points,like that sample image,i cant able get ur can u suggest me how to solve my prblm

Comment: ok,sory for asking line by line..in my code Gallery on click i am placing crop code...where i have to add ur sended code,dnt mind can you explain clearly

Comment: i mean u took one rect variable and for that u wrote one method,waher ur apply that code to image

Comment: in my code i didn't mention  those 4 points also by defauilt its comming

Comment: @MarkoLazić  hi Mark i have one question. on cropping usually we see 2 buttons namely 'Save' and 'Discard'. How can I put one more button named 'Discard' and save that one . Should I make costum crop class for that.. please tell..